# Logging Retrofit to Logback Logger

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, logback, retrofit

I'm developing a JAVA client for a REST API. I'm using Retrofit for the client. I see that I can set log level when creating adapter in retrofit. All this log currently goes to console. However, I want to redirect this to the log generated by logback which is already used in the application. How do I do this ?

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL).setEndpoint(APP_URL)
                .setRequestInterceptor(new AuthRequestInterceptor())
                .setErrorHandler(new RetrofitErrorHandler()).build();
```

Output

```
---> HTTP GET http://localhost:8080/services/v1/countries
Auth-Token: ...
---> END HTTP (no body)
<--- HTTP 200 http://localhost:8080/services/v1/countries (448ms)
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Thu, 04 Jun 2015 01:36:29 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
...

<--- END HTTP (9130-byte body)
```

I want all this to go to logger log.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `RestAdapter.Builder` also support passing it a [Log](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/parent-1.9.0/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit/RestAdapter.java#L112) using the [setLog](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/parent-1.9.0/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit/RestAdapter.java#L659) method.  `Log` is simply an interface.  Create your own Logback implementation of that interface and pass it to the builder when creating your `RestAdapter`.

```
public class LogbackLog implements Log {

    public void log(String message) {
        // call logback logger from here
    }
}

Log logger = new LogbackLog();

RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setLog(logger)
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL).setEndpoint(APP_URL)
            .setRequestInterceptor(new AuthRequestInterceptor())
            .setErrorHandler(new RetrofitErrorHandler()).build();
```